# Imacros to copy and paste based on each new line between </br> tag

Tags: javascript, copy, newline, extract, imacros

I have been trying to write this script where is takes information inside a div tag splits it into each line and pastes it into another form box serperately. Here is the information that I want to Split but will be different each time but brs will be in the same place:
</br>16" FRONT BIKE FORKS
</br> SUITABLE FOR CLALIPER
</br> STEERER DIAMETER: 1"
</br> THREADED
</br> STEERER LENGTH: 132MM

and then each line gets pasted into a different form. I just cant get the text to split properly with javascript

VERSION BUILD=8070701 RECORDER=CR
FRAME F=3
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Description
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:frm_amazon ATTR=ID:field_id_description_UK EXTRACT=TXT
SET VAR1 eval("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"content.split(/\s*<?/?br>\s*/),
SET VAR2 eval("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"content.split(/\s*<?/?br>\s*/),
SET VAR3 eval("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"content.split(/\s*<?/?br>\s*/),
SET VAR4 eval("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"content.split(/\s*<?/?br>\s*/),
SET VAR5 eval("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"content.split(/\s*<?/?br>\s*/);
PROMPT "VAR1={{VAR1}}, VAR2={{VAR2}}, VAR3={{VAR3}}, VAR4={{VAR4}}, VAR5={{VAR5}}"
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Information
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frm_amazon ATTR=ID:field_id_bullet3_UK CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frm_amazon ATTR=ID:field_id_bullet3_UK CONTENT={{!VAR2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frm_amazon ATTR=ID:field_id_bullet3_UK CONTENT={{!VAR3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frm_amazon ATTR=ID:field_id_bullet3_UK CONTENT={{!VAR4}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frm_amazon ATTR=ID:field_id_bullet3_UK CONTENT={{!VAR5}} 
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Description

Comment: use msi after / in regex

Comment: content.split(/<//br>/msi)

Comment: there is no such thing like `</br>` . Do you mean `<br />` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.split('</br>')[1];")
SET VAR2 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.split('</br>')[2];")
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks this splits in the correct places and into each var but now just paste undefined into each section rather than the text. What could be the cause?

Comment: Managed to fix it. I got rid of the ! before the var in the brackets for content. thank you so much